# Assign list element to a char*

Tags: c++, string, list, char

I've appends some elements in my list

```
std::list<std::string> dirList2;
//Code
dirList2.push_back(findData.cFileName);

copy(dirList2.begin(), dirList2.end(),std::ostream_iterator<std::string>  (std::cout,"\n"));
```

Everything work, i can view this items,

Now i want to assign the first elem of my list to a char* .

Can someone help me please ? i'dont know how to do it

Comment: See [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood well what you want then you can do it like this:

```
const char *s = dirList2.front().c_str();
```

Be careful, though. The C string which variable `s` points to is owned by the string object sitting on your list. If the list goes out of scope or you remove the element from your list, then the C string will be released by the `std::string`'s destructor and your `s` pointer will not be valid.

If you want to manipulate the C string beyond the liftime of the `std::string` object than you can do sth. like this:

```
const char *s = strdup(dirList2.front().c_str());
```

But it's usually better to use `std::string` instead of raw C pointers, unless you have no choice.

Comment: Regardless from actual sequence container type always use `front()` if you want first element.

Comment: @piokuc 
Thanks for your help, but it's don't work in my code..char*fileMask; fileMask = dirList2.front().c_str();
Error: a vaue of type"const char*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char*"

Comment: `char *s = (char*) dirList2.front().c_str();`

Answer (score 1):

The string object provides a `c_str()` method which will return a const char *. If you need to modify the string you must also make a copy of the string (IE using strcpy where the source pointer is the one returned by `c_str()`)